# Which Java class should I use to represent Git SSH URLs?

Tags: java, git, url, uri

I have a Git URL like `git@github.com:boostorg/core.git` that I would like to represent in memory.

I cannot use `URL` and `URI` because I get format exceptions. I would like to use something more structured than a `String`.

Does Java provide a good class from this?

Comment: Why you don't create a class for that.

Comment: @Càphêđen I could, but I would rather use a well-tested solution if it is available.

Answer (score 2):

As far as I know there is nothing like that in Java. You can write your own mini-class to represent that via String and for validating the URL you can use regular expression like this:

For a String s you can say:

```
s.matches(".+\@*.+:*\.git");
```

You can also use other regex to extract important part of the String.

Hope this helps

Answer (score 1):

How about creating your own class and splitting the url into fields?

Something like this:

```
public class GitUrl{
    private String user;
    private String domain;
    private String path;

    public GitUrl(String user, String domain, String path){
        this.user = user;
        this.domain = domain;
        this.path = path;
    }

    //[...] Getters and Setters

    @Override
    public String toString(){
        return user + "@" + domain +":" + path;
    }
}
```

Comment: The only thing I don't like, is that you overwrote the `toString()` method to do work. Personally, I would put that in a function such as `getUrl()`.

Answer (score -2):

You could specify it as SSH URL. From https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-on-the-Server-The-Protocols:

To clone a Git repository over SSH, you can specify an ssh:// URL like this:

```
$ git clone ssh://[user@]server/project.git
```

An SSH URL of this form is a valid URI and can be used with java.net.URI.

Comment: 5 years after the previous answers, this answer was added that does not add any value. It does not mention any Java specifics at all and the question already mentions "SSH URL" by name even.

Comment: There's value here in that an SSH URL is a valid URI and can be used with java.net.URI. The question was is there a Java class to represent an SSH URL, and I was pointing out that there is a valid URI one could use instead of what the OP was using. I should have explicitly said this will work with URI class. I'll update the answer. I stumbled on this question when looking into a similar problem, and so added the solution I had found for myself. Doesn't really matter how old the questions are when others may similarly stumble onto older questions.

Comment: I hadn't noticed the subtle difference. Apparently `user@server:project/repo.git` yields a `URISyntaxException` while `ssh://user@server:project/repo.git` works correctly... The gotcha is that even though the scheme is supposed to be optional in an URI, the parser could detect it wrongly when it is absent. A git url can contain `:` and the parser assumes everything before it is the scheme, but a scheme cannot contain `@`... This means that you can use the normal `URI` class as long as the scheme is explicit (be it `ssh://` or `https://` or `git://`).